# Plugin Export de Amcharts no descarga la data correctamente

Tags: javascript, json, excel, plugin, amcharts

El problema está cuando coloco un rango de tiempo e intento descargar la data  en formato .XLSX que alimenta el gráfico Amcharts.

Segun una consulta de 2 años deberían ser 19 columnas (Fijas) y unos 24 registros correspondientes a los 24 meses, al abrir el archivo descargado trae todas las filas correspondiente a los meses consultados pero solo trae unas 10 columnas de manera que queda incompleta la información.

Cabe destacar que en formato .CSV tambien ocurre este problema pero en formato .JSON si trae la información correctamente. Al igual que hay algunos meses cuyo valor en la columna es "vacio"

Ejemplo de descarga

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando en realidad deberia ser asi (.json convertido a .xlsx):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pareciera que al ver las celdas vacías en formato excel el Plugin salta con el siguiente registro, cuando en realidad debe colocarlo vacío y llenar la siguiente columna.